# React native build signed APK fails

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, apk

I have created a new project with react-native with few packages (react-native-camera, react-native-device-info, react-native-elements, react-native-geocoder, react-native-qrcode-scanner, react-native-vector-icons, react-navigation) but I cannot figure out why it doesn't build. I execute this command to generate the APK:

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleRelease
```

The output is:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:verifyReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

If I remove the react-native-device-info package, the error appear with the next installed package that is react-native-camera.

If I set android.enableAapt2=true (the error above it raised with aapt2 disabled) in the grade.properties I got this error:

```
D:\WorkingCopy\Apps\CpVehicle\src\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.
```

My build.gradle file is this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}


subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

When the project was at the beginnig, I built the APK without errors.

If I try to build it with Android Studio, It works fine but opening the app from the device it crash before appear. In the Play Store Console I got this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.cpvehicle, PID: 8053
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try this command before assembleRelease.
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ../../../apps/MyApp/app//src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ../../../apps/MyApp/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 21 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

Comment: Okay,so after this when you do `gradlew assembleRelease` is the exception still thrown?

Comment: D:\WorkingCopy\Apps\CpVehicle\src\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: Duplicate file.
D:\WorkingCopy\Apps\CpVehicle\src\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Comment: the error above if with android.enableAapt2=false. I got the error present in the question with android.enableAapt2=true

Comment: Try to remove backicon.png duplicate file and run `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Comment: I delete the \android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi-v4 \node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png file but when I launch the assemble command, It  recreate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174943/discussion-between-darion-badlydone-and-levon-petrosyan).

Answer (score 4):

I found out this solution or better a workaround:

1. disable aapt2 on gradle.properties

   android.enableAapt2=false
2. inside subprojects of build.gradle insert this:

   afterEvaluate { 
           project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
               android { 
                   compileSdkVersion 26
               } 
           }
       }